# Shell redirect: scons calls gcc, build error redirection doesn't work

Tags: shell, redirect, gcc, stdout, stderr

I was using scons(python build tool) which calls gcc to build a file, like this:

```
$scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o 1.o -c 1.cpp
1.cpp:20:5: error: no matching function for call to 'g'
    g(&obj2);
    ^
1.cpp:12:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'B *' to 'A &' for 1st argument; remove &
void g(A&a){
     ^
1 error generated.
scons: *** [1.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Then I try to save all output to a file. I suppose the error messages are in stderr, so I try to redirect fd=2 to fd=1 like this:

```
$scons 2>&1 >error1
1.cpp:20:5: error: no matching function for call to 'g'
    g(&obj2);
    ^
1.cpp:12:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'B *' to 'A &' for 1st argument; remove &
void g(A&a){
     ^
1 error generated.
scons: *** [1.o] Error 1
```

But seems error1 only contains information of "scons" command itself. All gcc error messages are still on screen, not saved in "error1"

```
$cat error1
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o 1.o -c 1.cpp
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So how to make all scons called progrems re-direct their fd=2 to fd=1? Or this is a limitation of shell redirection that only the top caller's stream could be redirected?

Comment: [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) appears extremely pertinent.

Comment: You could see this post as well: [In the shell, what does 2>&1 mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I haven't read through all the answers, but the question there doesn't appear to cover ordering between redirections -- which is more than a little pertinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirections are executed left-to-right, referring to the state of their destination as of the time when the immediately prior one completed execution.

- `2>&1 >error1` is executed with the following order of operations:

  1. FD 2 is pointed to whichever destination FD 1 was directed to when the operation started (since you're reporting that content is written to the screen, this is presumably your terminal).
  2. FD 1 is pointed to the file `error1`.
- `>error1 2>&1` is executed with the following order of operations:

  1. FD 1 is pointed to the file `error1`
  2. FD 2 is pointed to the location FD 1 presently points to (thus, *also* the file `error1`).

---

Thus, in the `2>&1 >error1` case, only FD 1 (stdout) -- and not FD 2 (stderr) -- is pointing to `error1`, since when `2>&1` is invoked, FD 1 is directed at the terminal.